# Styling images with Sass based on a dynamic ID

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have this bit of code that gets images from firebase and I'd like to style them individually, using the `data-image-id`(the `image.id` is retrieved from firebase) even though they're part of a larger container (`explore__all-art`).
How can I do so with Sass or is it at all possible? From what I read online, it is possible but none of the resources are specific to my issue.

Thank you!

```
  return (
    
    <>
      <div class="explore__all-art">
        {images?.map((image, index) => (
          <img
            key={index}
            src={image.url}
            alt={`Image ${index}`}
            // class={`image-${image.id}`}
            data-image-id={image.id}
          />
        ))}
        <button onClick={handleExploreDetails}> Explore </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

I tried using @each and @for, however I am so unfamiliar with the syntax and the documentation doesn't provide a lot of examples pertaining to react.

Comment: What do you mean by `style them individually`? Do you know beforehand which style will go on which `id`? Also can you post your css file so we can see what you have tried?